# How can I get mail received date using java mail api?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm sending a verification link to the email ID and that link should be valid for 24 hours. How can I do this in java?

Comment: You're talking about a token right? Let's assume you've an controller `/api/reset/{token}`. When a reset is toggled, a token is generated and stored inside of a database, of course with the related expiration date. If the user clicks at the link, the token is loaded from database and expiration can be compared... Is this a matching scenario?

Comment: That link itself is reset link. When reset is toggled, its hitting to spring mvc controller method.  I am setting null values to token name, serial number etc.

Comment: Reset is done. But when user clicks after 24 hours, again hitting to same method, setting null is not required,  reset is not required, instead it shoud pop up link is expired.

Comment: I am not loading any data from the database. No Comparision is done by loading data from the database. By taking email received date and current date and time, I think I can do..

Comment: How are you validating that the requested link is 24 hours old?

Comment: @prasingh  I have to do the same, but I am not getting how to do?

Comment: Then you should owner @0x1C1B comment. The thing is you have to persist the token somewhere. When the respective link is clicked then you have to compare that with persisted value.

Comment: Without persisting, by taking email received date and the current date is it possible to achieve?